# How to remove *ALL* unused symbols from a shared library?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

I have a code that I need to compile to shared library and remove ALL unused code from, but I can't find a proper solution. Here is a simple example:

```c
// test.cpp, compiled with GCC -fPIC -shared -fvisibility=hidden
#include <stdio.h>
class Foo {
    void bar();
};
void Foo::bar() { printf("hello"); } // unused and should be removed
// I'm using printf("hello") so I can detect the symbols with `strings`

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void test() {} // this function is "used"
```

`-fvisibility=hidden` makes it so that all functions are hidden by default, and I manually mark public functions with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`. However, hidden functions are not removed unless marked as `static` (which I can't do to C++ methods, obviously).

No matter what I do, GCC will always keep `void Foo::bar()` and `hello` around. Is there a way to remove these symbols without hacking the compiler? (yes, I am considering it at this point!)

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain _why_ you want to do this.

Comment: Uh, declare all the functions static?

Comment: @MatsPetersson: That won't work for C++ member functions.

Comment: @bmargulies: There are a lot of plausible explanations.  It could be a constrained environment, or it could link in a third-party static library of which it uses a small part, etc.  Stripping unused symbols can also cause dylib dependencies to disappear, so you can actually get a lot of mileage out of this sometimes.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? This smells like an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Wouldn't stripping symbols defeat the intent of a shared library?

Comment: @John: We are talking stripping non-exported functions, so the interface of the library is not affected.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Just internal ones for debugging?  I recommend against that.  I hate when my debugger shows me empty spots in my stack trace or just a sterile disassembly of library code my program messed up.

Comment: @John: No, internal **unused** ones. We are not talking debug information here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compile with the flag `-ffunction-sections`.  Then link with `-Wl,--gc-sections`.  I think that this can also be achieved with LTO, I'm not sure of the details.

Note that all public symbols in a dylib are considered live.  Only hidden symbols will be stripped this way.

Comment: That works, too, but I also found out about GCC's `-fwhole-program` flag which essentially marks every function as static, allowing for aggressive code removal (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: @user2662514: That only works if the source code for your library is contained in a single file.

Comment: @user2662514: The explanation behind this solution is that the linker does not check at the symbol level but at the section level (a section containing possibly many symbols). By passing `-ffunction-sections` to gcc you instruct the compiler to emit each function in a section of its own; you should expect it to significantly slow down the link phase but on the other hand the linker can now strip much more code out of the library.